# Find general solution and particular solution given a initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given this differential equation:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = te^{-x} $$

I want to;

(1) Find the general solution.

(2) Find the particular solution given the initial condition $x(0)=1$

So this is how i proceed:

$$ \int\frac{dx}{e^{-x}} = \int tdt \implies e^x = \frac{t^2}{2} $$

So if i take that last equation as a **general solution** for the initial condition $x(0)=1$ i have that: $$ 0 = ln \frac{1}{2}$$

So i think i am not doing it right and i would thank any kind of help.

Comment: Thank you for showing what you have done. I am working on an answer right now. Hold on for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given (with $x$ being a function of $t$):
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=te^{-x}$$
Separate, as you have done:
$$\frac{dx}{e^{-x}}=t*dt$$
Integrate both sides, as you have done:
$$\int \frac{dx}{e^{-x}}= \int t*dt$$
Notice that I added a **constant of integration**. This is where you forgot something.
$$\int e^x dx = e^x = \frac{1}{2} t^2 +C$$
Solve for the general solution:
$$x(t)=\ln\left( \frac{t^2}{2}+C\right)$$
Now plug in the initial conditions to determine the value of the constant of integration:
$$e^1=\frac{1}{2} 0^2+C \rightarrow C=e$$
Now plug in for $x(t)$:
$$x(t)=\ln\left( \frac{t^2}{2}+e\right)$$